# How to show only conditional labels on stacked bar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a bar graph and like to show only values with recent date on the stacked graph. My dataframe consists of four columns

```
Date <- c("18.Jun", "18.May", "18.Apr", "18.Mar")

variable <-c("LongNetEquity","LongTotalEquity","ShortNetEquity","ShortTotalEquity","NetEquity","NetTotalEquity","GrossNetEquity","TotalNetEquity", "NetEquityPerfAttr","GrossTotalEquityPerfAttr")

value<-c(88,86,77,65,34,12,56,89)

Criteria <- c("Above 70", "Between 60 & 70", "Between 45 & 60", "Below 45")
```

Below is the ggplot which I created so far :

```
ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = era, aes(x=variable, y=value ,fill=Criteria),stat="identity", alpha = 0.7) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red3","orange3","green3","yellow3"))
```

I like to show label on this graph with condition mentioned below :

```
label <- era[which(era$Date == "18.Jun"),]
```

I appreciate any help i get.

Thank you

Comment: What are the data "era"?

Comment: i guess i found the solution. it should be